# JFileChooser for directories on the Mac: how to make it not suck?

Tags: java, macos, jfilechooser

The JFileChooser in "directories only" mode on the Mac has two serious, crippling problems:

1) You cannot create directories with it

2) You cannot switch drives

This is rather a huge problem for my installer app. As far as I can tell, Apple provides no way around this problem, you can't even activate the non-native directory chooser ... so the only alternative is to find a free/open source pure-Java replacement widget.

Does anybody know of one?

Comment: This is a duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845403/how-can-i-make-a-jfilechooser-on-the-mac-that-lets-users-create-directories

Comment: ...except that the other question does not address the "switch drives" part.

Comment: Hmm, both were asked by the same person apparently, with 3 month interval in between...

Comment: Yes, that was me too. I registered this time.

The last question died without an answer (unfortunately "it's a usability thing" doesn't help me).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about using java.awt.FileDialog? It shows a native file chooser and allows creating new folders.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true");
    FileDialog d = new FileDialog(frame);
    d.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: That's for picking files, not directories. I don't think it's possible to select a directory with that widget.

Comment: I added the missing line to make it allow choosing folders. I use this in my commercial app to let users pick folders. It's much better than JFileChooser

Comment: I believe the behavior of `FileDialog` on OS X has changed. If you set `apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories` to `true`, you actually disable the selection of files, so only directories may be selected. By not setting any system property, OS X will allow you to select either files or directories.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that there is a magic property you can set that makes the awt filepicker do the right thing:

```
System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true");
```

I vaguely recall trying this before when I was on OS X 10.4 and it didn't work, but now I'm on Leopard and it does, so I'm a happy camper.

Answer (score 2):

JFileChooser *can* see external drives. Navigate down from the root into /Volumes and all drives are listed there. It's not elegant, but it works...

http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev///2008/Feb/msg00079.html

Answer (score 2):

I used JFileChooser with showDialog method and I did not have problem. I can create directories and sava as the file with the name that I like. If you use only showOpenDialog method you can not create directories